# Oozie workflow process multiple files in directory

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

**Use case:**

I have a coordinator which passes a directory with multiple files to a workflow.
The workflow has the following nodes:

```
    java node 1 :   Reads the file, and does some json parsing gets some input values to below nodes. Done using <capture-output>.
    pig node 1  :   Does some action. Requires above input values from parsed json.
    pig node 2  :   Same as above
    pig node 3  : ................
    ..................
```

**Problem:**

The coordinator passes a directory name to the workflow.
I want to be doing the below:

```
for every file in directory {
    java node 1 : get config from file X
    pig node 1  : ...............
    ..............
}
```

Please suggest a way using which I can do this.

**Below is the coordinator:**

LAST_ONLY

```
    <datasets>
            <dataset name="input" frequency="${datasetFrequency}" initial-instance="${datasetInitialInstance}" timezone="UTC">
                    <uri-template>${nameNode}/user/${coord:user()}/alertcampaign/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}/${HOUR}/${MINUTE}</uri-template>
                    <done-flag></done-flag>
            </dataset>
    </datasets>

    <input-events>
            <data-in name="inputLogs1" dataset="input">
                    <instance>${coord:current(0)}</instance>
            </data-in>

    </input-events>

    <action>
       <workflow>
             <app-path>${nameNode}/user/${coord:user()}/test.xml</app-path>
                   <configuration>
                            <property>
                                    <name>wfInput</name>
                                    <value>${coord:dataIn('inputLogs1')}</value>
                            </property>
                    </configuration>
      </workflow>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about to create loop with a [sub-workflow](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.6_Sub-workflow_Action)?

https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-write-an-el-function-in-apache-oozie/

https://github.com/rkanter/oozie-subwf-repeat-example